# What are consequences of going Cycles 3.0 Experimental to use Adaptive Subdivision?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, subdivision-surface, experimental-features

I'm a beginner, using 3.0. I don't work on production levels, just a hobby, but still it feels weird to go experimental(because of that warning).
I just watched a tutorial about Adaptive Sub division and it looked cool but I'm not sure if it's ok to use experimental features. I see professionals like Default Cube using just the oldest version(3.1 alpha for now) and not being scared of "consequences".

Finally, my question is: Do new problems emerge if I go Cycle 3.0 Experimental to use Adaptive Subdivision? And how to handle those problems?

Comment: Don't worry, go ahead and use it. Experimental just means it may not be fully flushed out, or they plan on making changes to it in the future (ex: maybe they don't like the way it's fitting with blender and are planning on replacing it with a different module). Or, it may just not be finished to the developer's liking and not ready to be labeled as a "supported" feature. Adaptive subdivision has been in the experimental category for a while - my guess is they were almost finished, but put more of their effort into finishing Geometry Nodes instead. There shouldn't be any problems using it.

Comment: Chris is right, adaptive subdivision have been under *experimental* for three years, and works just fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by @ChrostopherBennett in the comments of the question. Thank you. Copied:

> Don't worry, go ahead and use it. Experimental just means it may not
> be fully flushed out, or they plan on making changes to it in the
> future (ex: maybe they don't like the way it's fitting with blender
> and are planning on replacing it with a different module). Or, it may
> just not be finished to the developer's liking and not ready to be
> labeled as a "supported" feature. Adaptive subdivision has been in the
> experimental category for a while - my guess is they were almost
> finished, but put more of their effort into finishing Geometry Nodes
> instead. There shouldn't be any problems using it.